# Visual Studio 2008 SP1:

Tags: visual-studio-2008

'X', here, is a 3rd-party component implementing ICollection, and 'Y' is Count.  It compiles, temporarily removing the squigglies, and either shortly after (1-2 seconds), or after any edits are made in the text editor, shows red squigglies under Count.  ?! Any help would be mucho appreciated, thx.

edit:
for example,

```
ThirdPartyComponent instanceOfComponent = new instanceOfComponent();
instanceOfComponent.GetResults();

for(int i = 0; i < instanceOfComponent.Results.Count; ++i) {
    // Some stuff happens
}
```

Here 'Count' is squigglied, even though it compiles fine--and even shows up in Intellisense.

Comment: Missed the code sample, perhaps?

Comment: What type is "instanceOfComponent.Results"?

Comment: Also, what is the tooltip text when you hover over the red squigglies? Generally VS will tell you why it's complaining.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your comment above, it looks like VS is complaining about ambiguity between `Results.Count` and `Results.Count()`. It will compile fine, but it is warning you about this possible error. A cast to `ICollection` will explicitly tell the compiler which one to use:

```
for(int i = 0; i < ((ICollection)instanceOfComponent.Results).Count; ++i)
```

Comment: There's no ambiguity between Count property and a Count() method - different syntax means it is always clear which is required. Also, extension methods [such as Count()] are always last in precedence.

Comment: I couldn't find the right word, but I meant ambiguity in the sense that "maybe you meant to invoke the method but didn't"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what language you're using, but two possible problems here:

1. Count could be a function rather than a property.
2. More likely Results is actually a property returning a List<> based class and so you are calling the Count property of this Results object rather than the instanceOfComponent. A simple cast should solve it.

Comment: Yes, I'm thinking it should be Count(), not just Count by itself.

Comment: @Nicholas - Count is a valid read-only property on ICollection<T> and IList<T>; Count() is an extension method on IEnumerable<T>; so both are valid, though the property Count is preferrable.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add:

```
using system.linq;
```

Comment: Negative; when I added it, the entire iterator conditional (i < blahblah) got squigglied and VS said 'Count' was a method group.  It still compiles fine however.